# How to read the "predicted_true" Metric of an Azure ML experiment?

Tags: metric, azure-ml

I followed along to [Explore Automated Machine Learning in Azure Machine Learning](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-ai-fundamentals/Instructions/Labs/01-machine-learning.html)
 which had me create a regression experiment using data from https://aka.ms/bike-rentals (731 samples; 12 features; 1 label (rentals)).

The best model was a Voting Ensemble of two algos. The metrics have a *predicted_true* graph

[image]

which I had trouble understanding even after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-understand-automated-ml?view=azureml-api-2#predicted-vs-true):

> The true values are binned along the x-axis and for each bin the mean predicted value is plotted with error bars.

There are 9 bins here and there are 9 corresponding *Average Predicted Values*s (APVs) (one for each bin) (see table below to confirm this). But the blue line makes it seem like there's a whole continuum of *Average Predicted Value*s. Is the blue line just "connecting the dots" (i.e. the 9 APVs)? If there are only 9 APVs, then what's the meaning of the error bars (light blue regions)? What's going on on the right hand side? With the dip in the blue line and dip and arrowhead in the light blue region? The error bars dip to 0 at 4 different bins which coincide with the 4 bins that have 0 *Bin errors* in the table below, but the rest of the error bar doesn't seem to coincide with the other *Bin errors* values. E.g., for the `1,525.5 ~ 1,894.85` bin (the 4th bin from the right), the error bars seem to be around `1.5k` in the graph, but the *Bin error* for that bin is `258.847455318977` in the table below.

---

When viewed as table, the *Predicted vs True* data looks like this

[image]

and here it is in an actual table

| **Bin edges** | **Bin counts** | **Bin averages** | **Bin errors** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43-48.11 | 1 | 113.6912279 | 0 |
| 48.11-417.46 | 22 | 296.3723139 | 135.1174633 |
| 417.46-786.81 | 11 | 709.1647262 | 183.4718475 |
| 786.81-1156.16 | 21 | 994.882296 | 265.2700464 |
| 1156.16-1525.5 | 9 | 1293.40242 | 161.7881036 |
| 1525.5-1894.85 | 4 | 1692.202127 | 258.8474553 |
| 1894.85-2264.2 | 1 | 2151.197189 | 0 |
| 2264.2-2633.55 | 4 | 1548.323188 | 503.2679452 |
| 2633.55-2827 | 1 | 2281.890262 | 0 |